# Paypal upgrade- order details missing

Tags: paypal

My older version of paypal api in code was version 3. I took the files for paypal from

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/sdk

and the latest version which is going in the request is 74.

But Still I am not getting the order details in the paypal page even if I pass the values required in SetExpressCheckout service along with the other parameters

```
map.put("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0", "Test");
map.put("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0", "12345");
map.put("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0", "TestDesc");
map.put("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0", this.amount);
map.put("L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0", "1");
map.put("ITEMAMT", this.amount);
map.put("PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT", this.amount);
map.put("PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION", "Sale");
```

What am I missing?